# Transferring files from local desktop to SAS Server

Tags: sas

I am using SAS Studio remotely ( http://localhost:10800). I want to transfer data sets on my desktop to the SAS server. How would I do this?

Comment: To give a better answer would need to know more context (OS, clients you have available, permissions restrictions etc).

Comment: LOCALHOST does not sound like a remote connection. Are you using the free SAS University Edition version? If so then just copy the files into the folder on your PC that you shared with SAS when you configured the virtual machine that SAS UE is running on.

Comment: SAS Studio has an upload button, it's in the *Server Files and Folders* pane.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1) use FTP or other direct access mechanism to load files directly onto the server

2) if you have a local instance of base SAS, you might be able to rsubmit if you have the connection details (and SAS/CONNECT)

3) the fail safe (if volumes are small).  Export to CSV or generate a CARDS file (see this [macro](https://github.com/macropeople/macrocore/blob/master/base/mp_ds2cards.sas)) and copy paste the data into SAS Studio to rebuild the datasets using pure code.  Be aware that you may lose indexes and constraints this way unless you rebuild them also.